# django-scarface strange message trimmed on iOS push notification

Tags: android, ios, django, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I have a strange issue about iOS push notification and my django app.

In my djnago application I integrated `django-scarface` to send push notification to iOS and Android device using `Amazon AWS SNS service`.

In my test I can send push notifications to a generic device using a string message. I can receive correctly all notifications on my devices.

Now, if  I change the text of notification like this:

```
notification_message = notifications.settings.REQUEST_RECEIVED_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE % sender.from_user.first_name

REQUEST_RECEIVED_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "%s sent you a request!"
```

notification_message is correctly generated... for example I read `u"Safari sent you a request!"` (in debug mode)
but, when I receive the notification on iOS device I have something like this:

```
"Safari sent you...."
```

For some strange region my message is trimmed...

But, If I set hardcoded the name all works well: for example, if I have:

```
notification_message = notifications.settings.REQUEST_RECEIVED_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE % "SAFARI"
```

Have you some suggestion about this strange problem?